# Can a file change size when the transfer protocol changes?

Tags: windows-7, sync, smb, syncback

I am very curious about what I have just found happening on my computers.

I have set up SyncBackPro to synchronize a music folder from my home desktop to my laptop using Windows network share (SMB). Files get synchronized regularly.

Now I tried to switch to FTP and I noticed that **NO FILE** matches its counterpart even if they have never been modified (I make sure there is the readonly flag and no application is allowed to retag MP3s and whatever...), so SyncBack asks me what side should overwrite the other. FTP files are a little larger than local files.

I run synchronization from the laptop.

How can such a thing happen? Files are the same, bytes should be the same... If I run SMB sync again it matches all the files again.

Answer (score 2):

When files are transferred via FTP in ASCII/text mode, newlines will converted to the local form, which means that [lone CRs or LFs are being converted to CRLF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems). You should ensure that files are transferred over FTP in binary/image mode.

Comment: Surely the most probable cause. Though, I tried to force binary mode but I still get the same conflict screen :( I hope the last file I added are intact